# Sorting a list in scheme

Tags: scheme

How do write a sorting algorithm that returns a list into increasing order.

ex: `'(1 3 5 2 9)` returns `'(1 2 3 5 9)`

Comment: The question was already asked on Stack Overflow. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2527150/scheme-sorting-a-list

Answer (score 5):

Most Scheme implementations come with a procedure to sort lists. If your implementation does not provide one, it is not difficult to roll one on your on. Here is an implementation of the quick-sort algorithm:

```
> (define (qsort e)
  (if (or (null? e) (<= (length e) 1)) e
      (let loop ((left null) (right null)
                   (pivot (car e)) (rest (cdr e)))
            (if (null? rest)
                (append (append (qsort left) (list pivot)) (qsort right))
               (if (<= (car rest) pivot)
                    (loop (append left (list (car rest))) right pivot (cdr rest))
                    (loop left (append right (list (car rest))) pivot (cdr rest)))))))
> (qsort  '(1 3 5 2 9))
=> (1 2 3 5 9)
```

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit on how this program works? I have never seen let work like that and as far as I can tell it should not but obviously it does. It looks like loop is the entire code after let so why not just use lambda? I am not sure why let is used.

Answer (score 1):

[SRFI 95](http://srfi.schemers.org/srfi-95/srfi-95.html) provides a sorting library. Many Scheme implementation also have sorting libraries built in, though not all of them conform to the SRFI 95 interface.

---

If you need to write your own implementation (for homework, say), then you should use one of the standard sorting algorithms like mergesort or quicksort. However, both of those algorithms are vector-based algorithms, so you will need to copy the list to a vector, sort that, then copy it back to a list. (You may find [SRFI 43](http://srfi.schemers.org/srfi-43/srfi-43.html) useful for vector manipulation operations, especially [`vector-swap!`](http://srfi.schemers.org/srfi-43/srfi-43.html#vector-swap-bang) for swapping two elements of a vector.)

There may be algorithms that are suited for sorting a linked list directly. I'm not au fait with them, so I won't comment on them further.

Comment: Both mergesort and quicksort can be implemented pretty easily with lists, although you might lose a bit of performance in some spots where you have to traverse the list (although you maintain the same number of comparisons).