# check for permutation in Scheme

Tags: scheme, permutation

I need to write a function in a scheme that takes two lists and returns true if one list is a permutation of the other. 
For example 
`(permutation '(3 4 7) '(7 3 4))` would return #t 
`(permutation '(3 4 7) '(c 3 4 5))` would return #f

This is the code I got so far but I'm stuck:

```
 (define (permutation list1 list2)
  (cond
    ((equal? list1 list2))
    ((not (list? list1)))
    ((memq (car list1) list2) (permutation (cdr list1) list2))
    (else #f)
    ))
```

Thank you

Comment: You can easily sort each list and compare element wise. Check out the answer to this question [Sorting a list in scheme](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4297432/4408538)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have permutations if and only if

- removing the elements of `list1` from `list2` produces the empty list, *and*
- removing the elements of `list2` from `list1` produces the empty list.

If you had a function (let's call it "without") that removed all the elements of one list from another list, you could write

```
(define (permutation? xs ys)
  (and (empty? (without xs ys))
       (empty? (without ys xs))))
```

Assuming that you have a function `remove-first` that removes the first instance of an element from a list, you can define `without` using a fold:

```
(define (without xs ys)
    (foldl (lambda (x ls) (remove-first x ls)) ys xs))
```

All that remains is `remove-first`:

```
(define (remove-first x xs)
  (cond ((empty? xs) '())
        ((equal? x (first xs)) (rest xs))
        (else (cons (first xs) (remove-first x (rest xs))))))
```

(In your Scheme, `remove-first` may already be available as `remove`.)